# Hadoop-2.4.0 HBase-0.19.18 Region server startup failed

Tags: hbase, hadoop2

I have recently installed hadoop-2.4.0 and hbase-0.95.18 compiled with

```
sudo mvn clean package assembly:assembly -DskipTests -Dhadoop.profile=2.4
```

using below pom.xml options.

```
<protobuf.version>2.5.0</protobuf.version>
```

and

```
<id>hadoop-2.4</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.profile</name>
      <value>2.4</value>
    </property>
  </activation>
  <properties>
    <hadoop.version>2.4.0</hadoop.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
```

Here is my hbase-site.xml info.

```
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
      <value>hdfs://big7:54310/hbase</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>dfs.replication</name>
      <value>3</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
      <value>true</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
      <value>big11,big1,big4</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
      <value>2222</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
      <value>/home/hduser/hadoop/zookeeper</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
      <value>true</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

HMaster & Zookeepers are starting successfully but the regionservers are not starting. I got below error in the master log.

```
2014 -05-09 16:11:59,030 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.ServerManager: Registering server=big11,60020,1399632116991
2014 -05-09 16:11:59,038 INFO org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2014 -05-09 16:11:59,041 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.ServerManager: Waiting for region servers count to settle; currently checked in 1, slept for 100 ms, expecting minimum of 1, maximum of 2147483647, timeout of 4500 ms, interval of 1500 ms.
2014 -05-09 16:11:59,058 **ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster: Region server \00\00big11,60020,1399632116991 reported a fatal error**:
     **ABORTING region server big11,60020,1399632116991: Unhandled exception: Region server startup failed
     Cause:
     java.io.IOException: Region server startup failed**
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.convertThrowableToIOE(HRegionServer.java:1279)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.handleReportForDutyResponse(HRegionServer.java:1136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.run(HRegionServer.java:758)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: **This is supposed to be overridden by subclasses.**
        at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.getUnknownFields(GeneratedMessage.java:180)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.HBaseProtos$RegionServerInfo.getSerializedSize(HBaseProtos.java:883)
        at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite.toByteArray(AbstractMessageLite.java:62)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.createMyEphemeralNode(HRegionServer.java:1148)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.handleReportForDutyResponse(HRegionServer.java:1109)
        ... 2 more

2014 -05-09 16:11:59,768 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.ServerManager: Registering server=big1,60020,1399632116879
2014 -05-09 16:11:59,777 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster: Region server \00\00big9,60020,1399632116855 reported a fatal error:
     ABORTING region server big9,60020,1399632116855: Unhandled exception: Region server startup failed
     Cause:
     java.io.IOException: Region server startup failed
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.convertThrowableToIOE(HRegionServer.java:1279)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.handleReportForDutyResponse(HRegionServer.java:1136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.run(HRegionServer.java:758)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This is supposed to be overridden by subclasses.
        at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.getUnknownFields(GeneratedMessage.java:180)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.HBaseProtos$RegionServerInfo.getSerializedSize(HBaseProtos.java:883)
        at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite.toByteArray(AbstractMessageLite.java:62)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.createMyEphemeralNode(HRegionServer.java:1148)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.handleReportForDutyResponse(HRegionServer.java:1109)
        ... 2 more
```

Could someone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There are two .proto files that are compiled using 2.4.0

$HBASE_HOME/src/main/protobuf/ErrorHandling.proto 
$HBASE_HOME/src/main/protobuf/hbase.proto

Since you changed the protobuf.version, did you regenerate the .java files from .proto files using the protobuf-compiler version 2.5.0. This might be one of the problem.

You can do that using the following step.

1. Install protobuf-compiler version 2.5.0
2. Run the following commands in $HBASE_HOME/src/main/protobuf folder -

   $>protoc -I./ --java_out=src/main/java ErrorHandling.proto

   $>protoc -I./ --java_out=src/main/java hbase.proto
3. Recompile the hbase and start the server.

You can follow the discussion [here](http://apache-hbase.679495.n3.nabble.com/HBase-0-94-on-hadoop-2-2-0-2-4-0-td4058517.html) to know more on this.